# can we vacuum _delta_log folder in delta lake

Tags: delta-lake

We use vacuum to delete older data files in delta lake api.

1. does vacuum also delete files from _delta_log ?
2. if no, is there any way we vacuum _delta_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#remove-files-no-longer-referenced-by-a-delta-table):

> `vacuum` deletes only data files, not log files. Log files are deleted automatically and asynchronously after checkpoint operations. The default retention period of log files is 30 days, configurable through the `delta.logRetentionDuration` property which you set with the ALTER TABLE SET TBLPROPERTIES SQL method.

So you don't have to run anything to clean the `_delta_log`, old files are removed from it as new versions of the table are created.